# Origen y alcance de la expresión "palo de agua"

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, colombia, venezuela, panamá

Según el DAMER, la expresión "[palo de agua](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=palo)" (o según el uso cotidiano "palo de lluvia") hace referencia en Panamá, Colombia y Venezuela a una lluvia abundante e intensa:

> **o.** ǁ  ~ **de agua.** loc. sust. *Pa, Co, Ve.* Lluvia abundante e intensa. pop

Por ejemplo, en el libro *[Arrivederci Caracas](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=ot0Y2slwe5IC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=lluvia%20fuerte%20%22palo%20de%20agua%22&source=bl&ots=vwFfGFTpZb&sig=lAAz-7wXOntmOATdIe0O3tVeex0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKs5jr3c_cAhVF6KQKHbI6CUI4ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=lluvia%20fuerte%20%22palo%20de%20agua%22&f=false)* de Marisa Vannini aparece la expresión cuando habla de las lluvias:

> Era en verdad un palo de agua, fuerte, intenso, con truenos y relampagos

En Google Ngram aparece la expresión palo de agua hacia 1890 y palo de lluvia en 1985, pero no me queda claro el origen de estas expresiones y si solo es entendida en las zonas mencionadas o se entiende en otros países.

Comment: sera algo como jarabe de palo? osea que la lluvia cae como un palo ? a veces palo se ha utilizado para indicar fuerza o golpes. y pues el jarabe de palo es sangre que te sacan a golpes, y el palo de agua es el agua que cae como golpe.... hipotesis hipotesis...

Comment: Del origen, creo que habrá que creer en la respuesta de ukemi, pero en Colombia la expresión se que la usaban desde mis tatarabuelos o sea por lo menos desde finales del siglo XIX y probablemente desde antes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Estudios sobre el habla de Venezuela* da esta explicación:

> Creemos que hay que partir, para explicarlo, de palo de agua. El palo de agua es el aguacero: «No salgas, está cayendo un palo de agua.» En nuestra opinión, *caer un palo de agua* sustituye o traduce dos expresiones castellanas: *llover a chuzos, caer un chaparrón*. Tanto *chuzo* como *chaparrón* (derivado de *chaparro*) son palos. Llover a *chuzos* y *caer un chaparrón* (o una *chaparrada*) es como *caer un palo de agua*, como si cayeran efectivamente *palos*, como si la lluvia lo *apaleara* a uno. Y aun es posible que haya surgido como equivalente de *golpe de agua*, que en la lengua general es la caída abundante o copiosa de agua. La misma palabra *aguacero* se puede aplicar figuradamente, en el castellano general, a una gran cantidad de palos o golpes. «¡Menudo aguacero le cayó a cuestas!» *Aguacero de palos* registraba Pedro Montesinos en Lara para la lluvia intensa y copiosa. Morison, que ha seguido el derrotero de Colón para escribir su *Almirante de la Mar Océano*, «latigazos de agua» a los chubascos equinocciales que caen en el mar. Palo de agua se encuentra documentado desde Fidelia, de Gonzalo Picón Febres (1893). Y es más recio que el aguacero, que se ha atenuado algo y necesita el refuerzo del adjetivo: «Cayó un buen aguacero» o «un gran aguacero» (o un...
>
> - [*Estudios sobre el habla de Venezuela: buenas y malas palabras, Volume 1*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=usEuAAAAYAAJ&q=%22palo+de+agua%22), Monte Avila Editores (1987)

Comment: La hipótesis de que venga de _golpe de agua_ tiene sentido. Al fin y al cabo, tanto _palo_ como _golpe_ son partículas de uso bastante común en el habla coloquial (_¡qué palo!_, _llegó de golpe_ y demás).

Answer (score 1):

No puedo entrar al libro de Vannini, y no nos diste el párrafo, pero el enlace del diccionario da dos definiciones.  Además de la que mencionaste, está

> *Pa, Pe, Ch.* Instrumento musical hecho con una rama hueca de un cactus rellena de semillas y que, al moverlo, imita el sonido del agua.

Me imagino que primero se inventó el instrumento, y luego se empezó a hacer referencia al sonido del instrumento para describir una lluvia intensa (aguacero).

Para oír el instrumento: https://youtu.be/xu4ODqNJgPE

Comment: Ese instrumento es originario de Australia si mal no estoy y aquí en Colombia le dicen "palo de agua" a una lluvia fuerte desde la época de mis tatarabuelos. No creo que haya relación alguna. Ademas el instrumento suena como a una llovizna ligera y no a una tormenta tropical como a las que estamos acostumbrados en estas latitudes.